# video in html <video> is not playing in ios/iphone devices

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, html5-video

I have a webpage with a background as a video.
The video is well playing in desktop/laptop browsers and in android devices.

The problem is that the video is not playing on iPhone.
The sample code is given below

```
<div class="banner-container">
        <video src="assets/images/BannerVideo.mp4" autoplay muted loop  webkit-playsinline preload="auto" ></video>
    </div>
```

I also give the code in an alternate way

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline webkit-playsinline>
            <source src="assets/images/newphone.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="assets/images/newphone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           
</video>
```

But these both are not playing the video on an iPhone.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you share an example video which does not play - the issue may be the video itself?

Comment: I will share you the link for one such video.

https://www.pexels.com/video/a-man-using-a-computer-in-the-office-7989854/